# Remove the selector line under current Tab for a TabLayout

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I am using a TabLayout with 3 tabs. I customized the view of my tabs and therefor, I need to remove the following line under my tabs ( the screenshot doesnt come from my app):

[image]

I am ***NOT*** using a TabHost or a TabWidget and therefor, I cannot use `setStripEnabled(false)`. Setting the background to transparent doesnt change anything as well.

Here is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomcontent3"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/comtabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/compager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

All the answer I found were using `TabHost`, `TabWidget`. In my case, I'm using one `TabLayout` and three `Tab`. 
How can I remove this line in this case? Thanks a lot.

**EDIT** Some methods from TabLayout can't be resolved in my code for some reasons. There is the java code I use:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.comtabs);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);


        // add tabs
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());

        RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitytablayoutleft, container, false);
        RelativeLayout layout2 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitytablayout, container, false);
        RelativeLayout layout3 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitytablayoutright, container, false);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);



        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.compager);
        CommunityPagerFragment adapter = new CommunityPagerFragment(getChildFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);


        ((TextView)layout1.findViewById(R.id.tabtext)).setText(tabs[0]);
        ((TextView)layout2.findViewById(R.id.tabtext)).setText(tabs[1]);
        ((TextView)layout3.findViewById(R.id.tabtext)).setText(tabs[2]);



        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(layout1);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(layout2);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(layout3);
        //tabLayout.set

        return view;
```

and its import:

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As the two answers suggested, the key was the `tabIndicatorHeight` attribute.

However the method from the API was, for some reasons, unable to be solved. In this case you have to fix this directly from the xml, this way:

```
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
```

In your `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>` Layout.

As an example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/comtabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 19):

Even I faced the same problem recently. I came across the height xml attribute and changing it to 0dp did the trick for me.

```
app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
```

**OR**

Similarly I feel that changing the color attribute of the indicator to the same as the background of the tabs should also do it. I have not tested this solution but i think it should also work.

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="#9cc8df"
```

**The first option is better and it worked for me.**

None of these are as good as actually disabling the indicator but solve the problem regardless.

Comment: app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent" is a lot easier.

Answer (score 9):

I think the best solution is setting the tab indicator to null.

> app:tabIndicator="@null"

Answer (score 5):

For **TabLayout** you have to use this - "**tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);**"

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 4):

it seems there's API like;
`void setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int color)`
`void setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(int height)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int)

Comment: I can't resolve those methods. let me edit my main post with the java code, maybe it will help.

Comment: I found a way to apply this through xml instead. I'll upvote you :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can set tab indicator height to 0 to "remove" it, for example use:
`tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0);`

Comment: Are you using TabLayout from the Android Support Design Library?

Comment: TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs); then tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0);

Comment: Its exactly what I did. Still unable to resolve. Let me push my code in the main post.

Comment: I found a way to apply this through xml instead. I'll upvote you :) Thanks!

Comment: `setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight` was deprecated in support library 28.0.0 :( still works though