# How to remove TabLayout tooltip?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I´m currently working on adding a tablayout to my XML but I can´t figure out how to remove the tooltip when doing a longpress on the tab. Does anyone know?
Here´s an image of what it looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dnRe.jpg . It´s a WIP so it looks weird now

Here´s the tablayout

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl_crypto_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topSeparator"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
        android:tooltipText=""
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:tabTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: If you meant to remove the underline, pls follow this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388841/remove-the-selector-line-under-current-tab-for-a-tablayout

Comment: Not the underline but if you do a long press on a tab, it pops up a little view (tooltip) like you can see in the imgur link. I don´t want that view to show up

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually, by setting the TooltipText to null for every tab.

Kotlin:

```
for (i in 0 until tabLayout.tabCount) {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(i)?.view?.let { tabView ->
        TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(tabView, null)
    }
}
```

Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tatabLayoutbs.getTabCount(); i++) {
    if (tabLayout.getTabAt(i) != null) {
       TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(tabLayout.getTabAt(i).view, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the only solution works for me

```
   for (i in 0 until  binding.tabLayout.tabCount) {
        binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(i)?.view?.setOnLongClickListener {
            true
        }
    }
```